# SQLite - Count Distinct with three column groupings ignores last grouping

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on a database about directors from US companies. One specific table I've created from a query contains all directors who were in a company 5 years before it declared bankruptcy (query below):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS y_query AS
SELECT
  A.dir_id, A.linked_dir_ir, A.bankrupt_co_id, A.co_name, A.event_date,
  B.conn_co_id, B.conn_co_name, B.conn_co_type, B.conn_co_start_date, B.conn_co_end_date,
  (CASE WHEN conn_co_start_date >= event_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dir_hired
FROM (
  SELECT
    C.dir_id, C.linked_dir_ir, C.conn_co_id as bankrupt_co_id, C.overlap_start_date, C.overlap_end_date, C.conn_co_type,
    D.co_name, D.filing_date, D.event_date
  FROM director_network C
  INNER JOIN company_bankruptcy D
    ON C.conn_co_id = D.co_id
  WHERE (
    (C.overlap_end_date >= DATE(D.event_date, '-5 years')) AND 
    (C.overlap_end_date <= D.event_date))
  ) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN company_network B
  ON A.dir_id = B.dir_id;
```

(`linked_dir_ir` should read `linked_dir_id` but I'm on a slow computer and it would take ~1hr to change the column name)

So, that table is fine, the query takes a while to run but it works as intended. But now I need to count the number of directors (`linked_dir_ir`) a given director (`dir_id`) was associated (ie, each row is a connection) for each bankrupt company (`bankrupt_co_id`) the director was in, and each connected company (`conn_co_id`). There can be many lines connecting a pair of directors because a new entry is made if any of them receives a promotion and so on.

(A few rows of `y_query` table: [y_query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJXkU.png))

So, I thought this query would work, but I'm running into problems:

```
SELECT dir_id, bankrupt_co_id, conn_co_id, COUNT(DISTINCT linked_dir_ir) as conn_dirs
FROM y_query
WHERE bankrupt_co_id != conn_co_id
GROUP BY dir_id, bankrupt_co_id, conn_co_id;
```

I am not sure why but this query disregards the last group (`conn_co_id`) and the result is the same for any `dir_id` and `bankrupt_co_id`, where it should vary also based on what `conn_co_id` is. A sample of the result (it only changes when `dir_id` or `bankrupt_co_id` changes, as depicted):

[resulting query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXChD.png)

The result is the same as if I'd only grouped with `dir_id` and `bankrupt_co_id`, when it should be different for each `conn_co_id`. I've done a lot of research into `GROUP BY` statements and how it can be tricky, but I haven't been able to crack this one. I'd greatly appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to reproduce your result. But your query with multiple groupings seems to be fine. See example below:

```
CREATE TABLE test (dir_id INTEGER, bankrupt_co_id INTEGER, conn_co_id INTEGER, linked_dir_id INTEGER);
```

with some dummy data:

```
select * from test;
dir_id      bankrupt_co_id  conn_co_id  linked_dir_id
----------  --------------  ----------  -------------
1           1               1           1            
1           1               1           2            
1           1               1           4            
1           1               1           5            
1           1               1           6            
1           1               1           7            
1           1               2           1            
1           1               2           2            
1           1               2           3            
1           2               2           1            
3           3               2           1            
3           1               2           1            
3           2               2           1            
3           2               2           4            
1           1               1           3            
1           1               4           4
```

The query including your `conn_co_id` results in:

```
SELECT dir_id, bankrupt_co_id, conn_co_id, COUNT(DISTINCT linked_dir_id) as conn_dirs FROM test WHERE bankrupt_co_id!=conn_co_id GROUP BY dir_id, bankrupt_co_id, conn_co_id;
dir_id      bankrupt_co_id  conn_co_id  conn_dirs 
----------  --------------  ----------  ----------
1           1               2           3         
1           1               4           1         
3           1               2           1         
3           3               2           1
```

whereas without the top two results are combined:

```
SELECT dir_id, bankrupt_co_id, conn_co_id, COUNT(DISTINCT linked_dir_id) as conn_dirs FROM test WHERE bankrupt_co_id!=conn_co_id GROUP BY dir_id, bankrupt_co_id;
dir_id      bankrupt_co_id  conn_co_id  conn_dirs 
----------  --------------  ----------  ----------
1           1               4           4         
3           1               2           1         
3           3               2           1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's what I figured but it still puzzles me that the query doesn't work properly on my table. I wish I could make the example more reproducible but this dataset is proprietary so I can't really share more of it. Do you have any idea why the query might be behaving like that? I assume it's something to do with the table, that's why I put the query that created it in the post. I really appreciate your taking the time for this!

Comment: I've just figured out the problem was how I constructed the first query, so yes, this issue doesn't depend on grouping and aggregating functions. Thanks for the reply again

Comment: No problem, glad you found your bug! Cheers